# How to add watermarks to a pdf that has already embed in html code?

Tags: html, pdf, coldfusion

I am displaying a pdf in an iframe in my webpage. I am trying to add watermarks like "Sample" in the pdf file. Is there any possible way to do it with Javascripts, HTML, CSS or Coldfusion11?

In my webpage, depending on the user roles, I use the iframe to either disable the toolbar so that the users can't print or download the pdf, or enable it.

```
<cfif userroles EQ "admin">
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <br>
        <h1>ENABLE PRINTING AND DOWNLOAD</h1>
        <iframe src="myFile1.pdf" frameborder="0" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
<cfelse>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <br>
        <h1>DISABLE PRINTING AND DOWNLOAD</h1>
        <iframe src="myFile1.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" frameborder="0" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
</cfif>
```

Comment: You can use the `cfpdf` function of ColdFusion to add watermarks to PDF files. [See the documentation for cfpdf](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfpdf.html)

Comment: FWIW, that won't stop people from downloading or printing a PDF if they really want it. You can disable printing in the PDF's settings directly. You can also prevent editing and other functions related to manipulating PDF content using other PDF settings when the file is created.

Comment: Again, my disclaimer note: CF11 is EOL, so there won't be any more security updates. https://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2018/12/20/CF11_countdown_clock_is_ticking

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As what @Miguel-F said in his comment, I can use use `cfpdf` to add watermark as shown in  examples in [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfpdf.html) and [here](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/12/10/Proof-of-Concept-Working-with-Remote-PDF-Data).

What I've done is abit different, using a transparent `div` in front of the `iframe`. It does its job, and I can modify the "watermark". Below is my code.

`<div style="position:relative; top: -250px; font-size: 150px; color: grey; transform: rotate(-45deg);"/>SAMPLE</div>`

Thanks to all who guided me.

Comment: That doesn't actually satisfy your own requirement: *"users can't print or download the pdf, or enable it"* ;-). It's trivial to bypass it..